# How do you generate PDF/HTML/DOC in .NET?

Tags: .net, pdf, reporting, doc

Currently, we are producing reports by means of ABCPdf that transforms HTML to PDFs.
Now we need to generate DOCs as well. That is pretty close to reporting.
We've tried to replace ABCPdf with fyiReporting. But it is closely tied to its GUI databindings, and have poor programmatic API.

Ideally we want to have a set of report templates in our project + a simple programmatic API to pass the model object (complex .NET hierarchy). That will just produce files in common formats.

So what tool do you use to create PDF/DOC/HTML in .NET? Is anything lightweight available on the market for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm a glutton for punishment but when I need to create a Word document I actually almost always just write one from scratch using Open XML or create a template in Word and modify its XML. DOCX files are just zip files and although the default DOCX file has a dozen or so files you can actually whittle it down to just four files with a little tweaking, and three of those files you can generally leave untouched.

There's a great e-book from Microsoft called [2007 Office Document: Open XML Markup Explained](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15359) that walks you through the basics like runs and tables and styles and such.

For complex reports this probably won't work but if you're doing simple tabular stuff its actually pretty easy.